# Conjecture about primes and the greatest common divisor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures

Conjecture:

> Given $m,n\in\mathbb N^+$, one odd and one even, there are two
>   primes $p,q$ such that $|mp-nq|=\gcd(m,n)$.

I hope MSE can determine its validity.

From time to time, when testing my growing math packages [BigZ and Forthmath](https://github.com/Lehs/ANS-Forth-libraries), I recognize some patterns which I can't prove or disprove (or even have the ambition to). I post them here with the hope that it will not annoy too much. I hope you can bear with it.

Comment: I think it is true by [the structure of the solution set to Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity#Structure_of_solutions) and [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). EDIT: But some details need to be taken care of.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I was thinking the same thing. But the problem is: don't you need to show that two different arithmetic progressions have the property that the $n$th term of each is a prime for some $n$?

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan Yes, something like that. The two progressions should not "conspire" in a way that they never yield primes simultaneously. I do not know if this is technically hard to establish rigorously. But intuitively, Lehs's conjecture should be true.

Comment: I think this problem is equivalent to an unsolved version of Goldbach's conjecture. Take $m = 1$. Then essentially we're asking the following question: given a linear function $f(x) = a x + b$ with $a,b$ coprime integers, is there some prime $q$ for which $f(q) = p$ is also prime? Some googling suggests this is not known.

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan: What's a keyword for searching on this other conjecture of Goldbach?

Comment: @Lehs I think, Ashvin's version is a case of the Bunyakovsky conjecture. I share Ashvin's doubt that this special case is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $d=\gcd(m,n)$. By [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) there are two numbers $a,b\in\mathbb N$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ such that $|ma-nb|=d$. Then by [linear Diophantine equations solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations), all solutions to $|mx-ny|=d$ are of the form $x=a+kn'$, $y=b+km'$, where $n'=n/d, m'=m/d$. Therefore you are searching for the two arithmetic progressions $x_k=a+kn', y_k=b+km'$ to yield simultaneous primes for the same value $k$.

Since you asked for kewyords: This is conjectured (but not proven) to be true, and is called [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture), which is a particular case of the famous [Schinzel's hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H), which generalizes to polynomials of arbitrary degree (seeing arithmetic progressions as polynomials of degree $1$). Schinzel's hypothesis H encompasses many other important difficult conjectures, as the twin primes conjecture. The only result proven in this regard is [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), for just one arithmetic progression. A related conjecture is [Bunyakowsky's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), for only one polynomial of arbitrary degree.